# Multitarget rendering in two different spaces in one shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I make a program which work with a model in a worldspace. For my purpose I want to produce in the shader two textures:

1. In the worldspace, for postprocessing.
2. In the screenspace (as UV unwrap), for saving the result of working of shader in the current scene into a new texture of object.

I can't figure out how to do it in one shader with multitarget rendering. 
In the vertex shader I set position for both spaces:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec4 scrn_Position;
...
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position,1.0); 
scrn_Position = model * vec4(position,1.0);
```

In the fragmnet shader I set two outputs:

```
in vec4 scrn_Position;
...
layout (location = 0) out vec4 wrld_Color;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 scrn_Color;
```

But how to work with scrn_Position in the fragment shader? Is it possible to carry out in one pass?

Comment: Declaring `out vec4 scrn_Position;` in the VS and `in vec4 scrn_Position;` in FS? Or what are you asking about?

Comment: @Ripi2 Exactly! Fixed.

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you're trying to do, but I got the _impression_ that would you want to do can't be done with multiple render targets in a single rendering pass. I think you want two different rasterizations of the same primitive, w.r.t. different spaces.

Comment: @derhass Thank you!

Comment: Don't think so. You can certainly use scrn_Position as a variable, but the rasterizer will ignore it.